# Can cirrus clouds be created on Mars?

Tags: mars, terraforming

On Earth we are thinking about reducing the cirrus clouds to cool off the planet Earth, but can cirrus clouds be created to add to Mars' atmosphere and keep the heat from escaping into space?

Comment: "On 18 September 2008, the Martian Lander Phoenix took a time-lapse photograph of a group of cirrus clouds moving across the Martian sky using LiDAR" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrus_cloud#Extraterrestrial

Comment: FYI, I edited your title to something that is less conversational and opinion based sounding. As you're new here, you might not realize that Stack Exchange tries to adhere to a strict question and answer format.  You can, of course, roll back my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: Thank you for the editing Organic Marble, as I understand about editing and proofreading, as I have someone working on my science fiction mystery story that was released back on November of 2014.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [NASA article](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/watch-martian-clouds-scoot-thanks-to-nasas-curiosity), cirrus-like clouds occur naturally on Mars:

> Wispy, early-season clouds resembling Earth's ice-crystal **cirrus clouds** move across the Martian sky in some new image sequences from NASA's Curiosity Mars rover.
>
> [...]
>
> "It is likely that the clouds are composed of crystals of water ice that condense out onto dust grains where it is cold in the atmosphere," said Curiosity science-team member John Moores of York University, Toronto, Canada.

The article describes cloud formation early in the morning, during the season when Mars is farthest from the Sun.  [Another NASA article](https://mars.nasa.gov/news/8956/nasas-curiosity-rover-captures-shining-clouds-on-mars/) shows other clouds seen in the twilight after sunset, and has better pictures:

[image: clouds on Mars]

[image: animated gif]

The second article suggests that Mars clouds can be created by either water or carbon dioxide crystals:

> Most Martian clouds hover no more than about 37 miles (60 kilometers) in the sky and are composed of water ice. But the clouds Curiosity has imaged are at a higher altitude, where it’s very cold, indicating that they are likely made of frozen carbon dioxide, or dry ice.

A [third NASA page](https://mars.nasa.gov/MPF/science/clouds.html) has more pictures of Martian clouds.

It is therefore plausible that seeding Mars' atmosphere with more water would increase the presence of clouds.